# Delete just one side of a manytomany relationship Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables that have a manytomany relationship:
first one is ad ( represents all the products)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ad")
public class Ad {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "admin_id")
    private Admin admin;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ads", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
```

Second one is order:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`order`")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;


    @ManyToOne( cascade=CascadeType.
    @JoinColumn(name = "buyer_id")
    private Buyer buyer;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "order_ad", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "ad_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private List<Ad> ads = new ArrayList<>();
```

when I delete order using its repository that is representing a cancellation so I don't want the ads to be deleted as well.
How can I do that?
PS: I can't find a replacement for the orphanRemoval of the onetomany relationship

Comment: Why would an Ad be deleted? Try deleting your Order and see - what you want is the opposite of an orphan removal operation. Note that in this ManyToMany bidirectional relationship that Order controls the join table - when it is deleted, the entries in the relation table are automatically cleaned up, but it doesn't cascade to the Ad unless you tell it to.

Comment: Maybe you find this article useful: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/  Btw. do you really need a many-to-many relationship? Does the "Ad" need to know about the Orders? You could just have an order with a list of Ads (oneToMany). In case you ever want all the Orders that include an "Ad", you can write a query for that.

Comment: @Chris it actually cascade to Ad, if in the order, some ad has been ordered 5 times, when i delete the order, the quantity of the ad is reduced by 5

Comment: You must have some other settings telling JPA/Hibernate to cascade the delete if it is happening, as what you've shown here will not remove Ads if all you are calling is em.remove(order). Maybe you have some on delete cascade option set on the foreign keys in the database? Show the SQL that is issued and the removal code

Comment: found the problem, it was in the order of the save(Ad) and delete(order) that i was making, works fine now

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer that article starts with a class example using a fixed hashcode of 31, and then makes is wrong descriptions of the difference between orderBy and orderColumn - both can affect the SQL and use an order by clause in queries - the diff is order is app controlled on one while the other is controlled/set by JPA directly. If Hibernate is removing all entries for a particular key and reinserting them - file a bug to get the behaviour changed, as other providers don't do this. There should be no need to remove all entries where post_id = 1

Comment: Unfortunately JPA does not allow deleting just one side of relationship. It must be done with native SQL. If you don't want to write this SQL as a string, you may use https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/JPA-Integration